# Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra and SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

[Here is the pdf](http://www.math.utah.edu/~zwick/Classes/Fall2012_2270/Lectures/Lecture35_with_Examples.pdf) I am using to learn SVD Decomposition. On page $2$, it states how the eigenvectors from non-zero eigenvalues of $A^{T}A$ are in the rowspace of $A$ and how eigenvectors from non-zero eigenvalues of $AA^{T}$ are in the columnspace of $A$. Why is this true?

Comment: Can you see that every vector of the form $Ax$ is in the column space of $A$?

Comment: Yes I do see that ....but what of it? @ErickWong

Comment: All I can see so far is that if x is an eigenvector and c is a nonzero eigenvalue, we have AA^(T)x = cx... if we look at A(A^(T)x) = cx, then this is saying a combination of the columns of A equal a multiple of x so then x is in the columns space of A? @ErickWong

Comment: That's the entire proof!  The last point is slightly more clear if you say that $A( A^Tx/c ) = x$, which makes it more obvious how you're using $c\ne 0$.  The other half follows identically from every vector of the form $A^T x$ being in the row space of $A$.